# Proofs needed for observations regarding prime-partitionable numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

Below, is the definition of a **prime-partitionable** integer taken from W. Holsztynski, R. F. E. Strube, [Paths and circuits in finite groups](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X78900596), Discr. Math. 22 (1978) 263-272 and is apparently the same in W. T. Trotter, Jr. and Paul Erdős, [When the Cartesian product of directed cycles is Hamiltonian](https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1978-49.pdf), J. Graph Theory 2 (1978) 137-142 DOI:10.1002/jgt.3190020206:

An integer $n>=2$ is said to be prime-partitionable if there is a partition {$P_1,P_2$} of the set $P$ of all primes less than $n$ such that, for all natural numbers $n_1$ and $n_2$ satisfying $n_1+n_2=n$ we have that either $gcd(n_1,p_1) \ne 1$ or $gcd(n_2,p_2) \ne 1$ or both, for some pair $(p_1,p_2) \in P_1 \times P_2$.

Conjectures:
If $P_1 =$ {$p_{1a}, p_{1b}$}, $p_{1a}$ and $p_{1b}$ are odd primes and $p_{1a}< p_{1b}$, it appears that, if $\psi = kp_{1a} + 1 = p_{1b} + p_{1a}$ for $k$ odd and $1 < k ≤ p_{1a}-2 $ then:

1. $\psi$ is prime-partitionable,
2. no two values of $p_{1b}$ are the same and
3. the number of values of $k$ is $≥ 1$ for each $p_{1a} ≥ 5$.

The following six sequences in the OEIS contain the results of my investigations into prime-partitionable numbers and their equivalence to Erdös-Woods numbers:

A059756, A244640, A245664, A249302, A245372, A259560

Can proofs be found for the conjectures please.

Comment: Can you edit this so it's readable? Is $n_1$ the same as $n1$? Does $<>$ mean $\ne$? Is $P1XP2$ meant to be $P_1\times P_2$? Is $pp$ just the name of a variable? And what does that dangling doi do?

Comment: I hope this is better now - I am on a formatting learning curve.

Comment: Better...still not entirely clear. So it does appear that you are using $pp$ as the name of a variable, not a common practice in math. Observation 3 no verb. Also, Trotter had a co-author for that paper, fellow named Paul Erdos. And the first paper was 1978, not 1987.

Comment: Prime-partitionable numbers are mentioned at https://oeis.org/A244640 and https://oeis.org/A059756, along with some links and references.

Comment: Corrected references and added links to the papers.  Replaced $pp$ by $\psi$. Verb introduced in 3rd conjecture.  Included references to related OEIS sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume a limited (and unproved) version of Linnik's theorem:  There is a prime $q$ of the form $kp + 1$ for $k \leq (p-2)$ and $p$ a prime.  Experimentally this is true, and can be proved for many primes, but at present not all.  With this in hand, the proofs of the conjectures are exercises:

- 1) note that any number $n= n_1 + n_2$ with $n_2$ coprime to all but at most two primes less than $n$ must either have $n_2=1$, or else $n_2$ must have a prime factorization consisting of  at most those two singled-out primes.  Throw in the other conditions (and the assumption), and we get that $n_2$ is 1 or one of the two primes.  Now the additional equations have to be satisfied for $n$ to be prime partitionable with respect to the given partition.  The only problem is the existence of $k$ of the desired form, which we have already taken as an assumption.
- 2) Not sure what this means, but if $p_{1a}$ is fixed and $k$ varies, the primes $p_{1b}$
  will vary.
- 3) If the first prime is 3, that restricts things too much.  If it is 5 or greater, the assumption quickly yields the result.

So for a given number $n$, it is prime partitionable with respect to a special partition (the first part consisting of two primes) if it has the form given by the equations and restrictions involving $k$, and our assumption above holds.  However, the assumption is a strong version of Linnik's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions, and is the chief reason why an otherwise simple exercise remains a conjecture.

Gerhard "Deep Thoughts Upon Shallow Problems" Paseman, 2015.08.03

Comment: Actually, we need to make exceptions in the assumption for p=2 (so k=1) and p=3 (so k=2).  However, for larger primes p, small even values of k seem to work.  Gerhard "Except For Finitely Many Exceptions" Paseman, 2015.08.03